# Is there a way in a Scala after() method to know whether the test failed?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a test suite that implements `BeforeAndAfter`, and I'd ideally like to be able to check in my `after()` method if the test failed, and if it did calculate some value and print it out. Is there an inbuilt way of doing this?

ps. I know I can do a try/catch around the whole test but I'd rather not have to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in `after()`, however you can do it by overriding `withFixture()`. This method runs the actual test, after that you can match the result and print something in case of failure:

```
class ExampleSpec extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {

  "Example" must {
    "work correctly" in {
      3 must be(3)
    }

    "not fail" in {
      true must be(false)
    }
  }

  override def withFixture(test: NoArgTest) = super.withFixture(test) match {
    case failed: Failed =>
      val nameLen = test.name.length
      info(s"The test '${test.name}' failed")
      info(s"The test name is $nameLen characters long")
      failed
    case other => other
  }
}
```

See [Sharing Fixtures](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_fixtures), especially the section "Overriding withFixture(NoArgTest)"

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, you can:

1) write something like `def around[T](code: => T) = try {code} ...` and use it like:

```
    test("mytest") {
       around {

       }
    }

    it should "blabla" in around {
       ...
    }
```

2) If you don't use specs then just write your own:

```
    def mytest[T](name: String)(code: =>T) = test(name){
      try {
        code
      } ...
    }
```

or just override `test`:

```
   override def test[T](name: String)(code: =>T) = super.test(name){
      try {
        code
      } ...
    }
```

Both can be done in separate trait, btw.

3) Override `withFixture` as it described @alextsc's answer

4) Write your own [reporter](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner) if you want to intercept all tests in your build

P.S. BeforeAndAfter/withFixture are meant to clean up resources (that's why they don't give you any access to exception), so logically reporter solution might fit better if you need to analyze and rerepresent your errors, but it's not much convenient.